# SQL msaccess insert single value into table

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

In my MSAccess database, I have this textbox "ProductName" where a user enters a value and presses a button to insert the value at the bottom of the table "Product".  The column I want to add it to is "Product_ID" and my sql statement is

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Tables!Product (Product_ID) VALUES ('" & Me.ProductName.Value & "')"
```

I found that this is breaking my code and I have been trying to fix it but cant seem to figure it out

I have also tried this

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Tables!Product (Product_ID) VALUES ('" & Me.ProductName.Value & "')"
```

Comment: Is "Tables!Product" the table name? You should add your database schema to your question.

Comment: yes, and i just tried "Product" and it seemed to work, I thought I had to use "Tables!Product" to select the table I wanted

Comment: The exclamation mark is a VBA syntax feature not an Access SQL syntax feature.

Comment: There is no need to reference the Tables collection to specify the table and as you learned, it doesn't work in SQL anyway.

Comment: So, problem solved? Or need help yet?

Comment: @harun24hr  The problem was solved, instead of "Tables!Product" I had to have just "Product" and it resolved my issue